# How to center text in container?

Tags: flutter

The code I wrote places text in container in the center of the first line and I need it to be in the center of the full square (middle line).

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      textFormfield1('name', Controller),
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Add at 3 images',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                    //color: Colors.grey[400],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16))
          ]),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
          child: Text(text,        
          textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow)));
          )
),
```

Pic of what happens and what I need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGbXX.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your question completely, but I made a dartpad file to help the discussion here: http://dartpad.dev/104cfd9d2c9ced1147c8b0b45454e538. Perhaps you could refer to that when you're explaining what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for answer, I made a quick sketch of what I try to do: https://imgur.com/a/FWdjPYX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) with a [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget.

```
Center(
 child: Text('Your text')
);
```

So in your context

```
Container(
 child: Center(
  child: Text('Your text')
 )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the alignment attribute of Container widget like - `alignment: Alignment.center,`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) Widget in a [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) Widget.

```dart
Center(
 child: Text('Your text')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Center Widget as a parent of column widget and set the crossAsixAlignment proper to center.

```
    Center(
    child: Column(
    crossAxisAligment: CrossAxisAligment.center,
    children : [
    const Text('This is centered'),
      ]
    ),
)
```